# Concatenate columns and use the column names as a binary feature in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a DataFrame with two columns that contain the same type of data:

```
id   foo   bar
1    f1    b1
2    f2    b2
3    f3    b3
```

I know how to concatenate the two columns, but I would also like `foo` and `bar` to appear in an additional column as a binary feature indicating which column they originally came from, like so:

```
id   foobar  column
1    f1      foo
2    f2      foo
3    f3      foo
4    b1      bar
5    b2      bar
6    b3      bar
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm a little confused, you mention concatenating columns, but I'd expect that to result in `f1b1`, not adding all the values into one column. Am I misunderstanding pandas terminology or have you made a typo?

Comment: A cleaner way to achieve this (so you don't lose the id) can be done with pd.concat([df[k] for k in df], keys=df.columns)

Comment: Do you care overmuch about "foobar" being the name of the new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df = DataFrame({'foo': ['f1', 'f2', 'f3'], 'bar': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']})

print df

  bar foo
0  b1  f1
1  b2  f2
2  b3  f3

cols = ''.join(list(df))
df = concat([df.foo, df.bar], keys=df.columns).reset_index(0)
df.columns = ['source', cols]
print df

  source barfoo
0    bar     f1
1    bar     f2
2    bar     f3
0    foo     b1
1    foo     b2
2    foo     b3
```